# mvn.riptano.com not authorized connection, connection require authentication

Tags: maven, repository

I'm trying to launch the Bamos Server (a BAM tool from the book SOA Governance in Action from the author Jos Dirksen), when i check out all the bamos-* projects and try to mavenize them specially bamos-core project i hit into a problem :

> http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized ,
>   ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.

More details:

```
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-esper:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-esper:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-esper:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-esper:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.services:bamos-extensions-services-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.services:bamos-extensions-services-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.services:bamos-extensions-services-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.services:bamos-extensions-services-ipinfodb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-nagios:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-nagios:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-nagios:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-nagios:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-wso2registry:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-wso2registry:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
 PKT: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-wso2registry:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of riptano has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bamos.extensions.processors:bamos-extensions-processors-wso2registry:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to riptano (http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/releases refus any connection without authenticiation. It seems that it's the case since 11/25/2013, the mvn.riptano.com repo has changed to require authenticaion and I am not sure why.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have fixed something, as this now works:

http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/

However, the URL:

http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/releases/

which used to work without authentication now requires it.

I discovered this when trying to figure out why that proxy was blocked in our Nexus.  When I first set it up it was configured to use the .../releases URL, which definitely worked at the time.  I just changed it to use .../public and it works again.