# Open Source BAM solution that accepts REST requests and provides REST interface?

Tags: rest, events, wso2-bam

As I want to set up a BAM solution, I'm wondering if there's any Open Source BAM solution that accepts REST requests as events and provide a REST interface to query for events ?

I found a BAM Open Source solution created by Jos Dirksen author of the SOA Governance in Action but I couldn't get the maven dependencies from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public/ repository (ref: [mvn.riptano.com not authorized connection, connection require authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457678/mvn-riptano-com-not-authorized-connection-connection-require-authentication)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [1] you can find how to publish data to WSO2 BAM 2.4.0. There, first you should create a stream (which is a predefined set of fields to be published) using REST API. Then you can send data to BAM via REST API. All the data will be saved in Cassandra where you can analyze data in it using a Hadoop cluster and summarize data. In most cases summarized data is stored in RDB where these data can be visualizes in a dashboard or generate a report.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Sending+Events+through+the+REST+API

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to send data (REST/JSON) to WSO2 BAM through Apache CXF using an interceptor that implements RequestHandler and ResponseHandler ? Example:                                                    String jsonData = createJSON(server, serviceName 
, classifier
, Integer.toString(response.getStatus())
, Long.toString(processedAt - receivedAt));
sendRequestAsynchronously(jsonData);                                                                     Or i have to define a stream using REST API ?

Comment: I do not know about CXF way. But as I know anyway you can define the stream using REST API as mentioned in the given document.